# MySQL: Fetch records related to current record in same table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a MySQL query which can extract all the items, which match a search term. The search term can match either the `id` or the `title` - this I've got covered.

I would also like it to return any children the matched item might have. So at the moment I am using the following query: (search term: "parent item")

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`id` LIKE "%parent item%" OR `title` LIKE "%parent item%")
```

Which returns:

```
id     | title       | parent_id
------ | ----------- | ---------
15     | parent item | 0
```

But I have now gotten stuck trying to figure out how to return something like this:

```
id     | title       | parent_id
------ | ----------- | ---------
15     | parent item | 0
34     | child item  | 15
45     | child item  | 15
58     | child item  | 15
```

I'm using PDO to connect to the Database, so keeping it to one line is, as far as I know, necessary..

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Found a solution after quite a bit of trial and error.. I've added my answer below, but this is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT
    t2.id AS id,
    t2.title AS title,
    t2.parent_id AS parent_id,
    t1.title AS parent
FROM
    `mc_sets` AS t1
RIGHT JOIN `mc_sets` AS t2
ON
    t1.`id` = t2.`parent_id`
WHERE
    t2.id LIKE "%parent item%" OR t1.title LIKE "%parent item%" OR t2.title LIKE "%parent item%"
```

Output:

```
id     | title       | parent_id | parent
------ | ----------- | --------- | ----------
15     | parent item | 0         | null
34     | child item  | 15        | parent item
45     | child item  | 15        | parent item
58     | child item  | 15        | parent item
```

If you have any ideas on how to improve it, or a different solution, please feel free to share :D

Comment: you said search term can match either the id or the title But in your desired result Search term is matched to what ?? except that 1st one title  - parent item

Comment: The search term is "parent item" which matches the top result (id=15), and then I would like to also fetch all the records with the matched id (15) as the parent id.

Comment: I have update my question with the solution I found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a bit of trial and error..

I discovered that you can give tables an alias, so I was able to join the table with itself where an item has a parent, thus allowing me to match the search term to the parent's title.

This works:

```
SELECT
    t2.id AS id,
    t2.title AS title,
    t2.parent_id AS parent_id,
    t1.title AS parent
FROM
    `mc_sets` AS t1
RIGHT JOIN `mc_sets` AS t2
ON
    t1.`id` = t2.`parent_id`
WHERE
    t2.id LIKE "%parent item%" OR t1.title LIKE "%parent item%" OR t2.title LIKE "%parent item%"
```

Outputs:

```
id     | title       | parent_id | parent
------ | ----------- | --------- | ----------
15     | parent item | 0         | null
34     | child item  | 15        | parent item
45     | child item  | 15        | parent item
58     | child item  | 15        | parent item
```

Was quite a tricky one... Thanks for your answers and suggestions!

Comment: This one better so i m deleting my answer to make thread clear

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to join the tables together, maybe try something like this.

```
SELECT p.Id, p.title, c.Id, c.title 
FROM Parent p, Children c
where p.Id LIKE "%parent item%" and
p.title LIKE  "%parent item%" and
p.Id = c.ParentId
```

Comment: How do you know which is parent and which is child?

Comment: Every record has it's own ID, and all records can be a child of another record, in which case they have a PARENT_ID, which is the ID of the parent record... if that makes sense..